# If not hovered then close or don't do that again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Hi **stackoverflow comunity**!

I have fully working code below, but i want to enchant it. Current code work like this: when I hover .buy my .popover is shown and after I leave a .popover , .popover will be closed, and what I want from my code to do is when .popover will be hovered and shown disable first code in function or something like that just doesn't show once again that .popover, I know it's hard to understand me (maybe), but I hope that you will find a solution.

```
 $(".buy").bind('mouseenter', function () {
      $('.popover').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('animated fadeInDown show').css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".popover").bind('mouseleave', function () {
      $('.popover').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('animated fadeOut');
    });
```

Image/GiF
https://imgflip.com/gif/8l5ry

Thanks for answers and comments

Comment: When you have to explain a complicated question it's a good idea to reproduce the problem and show what output you want using http://jsfiddle.net and/or images.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @DavidThomas latest v1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable that indicates if `.popover` has been hovered before.

```
var showPopover = true;

$(".buy").bind('mouseenter', function () {
    if (showPopover) {
        $('.popover').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('animated fadeInDown show').css("display", "block");
        showPopover = false;
    };

});
$(".popover").bind('mouseleave', function () {
  $('.popover').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('animated fadeOut');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( and I have tried changing the showPopover in code.

Comment: popver is still created while i hover on .buy.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No, but i will work on it, Simply when popover is open do not create next if mouseleave allow creating so if you will have some free time feel free to edit your question and i will mark it as right. Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to close the `.popover`s manually and ensure that only one `.popover` at a time is open? Maybe you can try to be a little more clear.